# Configuring JSHint for Vim

Tags: javascript, jshint, vim-plugin

I recently installed JSHint to help me out debugging some Javascript code.
JSHint seems to be working flawlessly but now I want to tweak it to suit me better.

For exampled. I want to disable warning "WXXX", error "EXXX" or add some settings. How would I do this using a global .jshintrc file?

Currently I have ~/.jshintrc that looks something like this:

```
{
   //Settings
   "debug": true',
   "devel": true',
   //And some more settings

   "-WXXX": false,
   "-WXXX": false,
   "-EXXX": false
}
```

But as far as I can tell this is doing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

To disable a warning, you have to use `"-WXXX": true`.

You can't disable errors (`EXXX`): http://jshint.com/docs/

> This syntax works only with warnings (code starts with `W`), it doesn't work with errors (code starts with `E`).

Comment: Yeah I read it on the docs that errors couldn't be disabled. Just checking anyways :) How do I know is JSHint loaded my .jshintrc file correctly? I still get a lot of warnings even if I use true instead of false.

Comment: Try to create a file which just contains `let a = 2;` and lint it: you should get a warning. Then add `"esversion": 6` to your .jshintrc file: if the warning disappear, the configuration has been loaded correctly. Otherwise, jshint has a bug, because it should work (http://jshint.com/docs/cli/, "Specifying Linting Options", 4)

Comment: This doesn't work. Seems like JSHint can't find the .jshintrc file.
My -jshintrc location: ~/.jshintrc
My project location: ~/dev/bla/bla/bla/app.js
If I move the .jshintrc file into the project folder it works. Why can't I have it in my users folder? I though this was the way to have a global .jshintrc file.